# Hiding AvalonDock LayoutAnchorablePane WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, avalondock

Hi I am new to WPF and am working on an existing xaml. I have to hide a LayourAchorablePane when the screen opens. I have tried the isVisible property but it does not work.

Please help me on methods to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**LayoutAnchorablePane** hosts **LayoutAnchorable** which can be autohidden.**LayoutAnchorable** doesn't have a dependency property to which you can bind to or set value from XAML. However you can assign a name to **LayoutAnchorable** and call

> layoutAnchorable.ToggleAutoHide();

You can also use the **IsAutoHidden** property to check whether it is already hidden.